# How to Audit two tables with one-to-one relation through hibernate envers?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

So I have two entity classes, **Subscription** and **MailDetail**. There is a one-to-one relation between them.
Here are the classes -

Subscription.class-

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
public class Subscription {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =`enter code here` GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "subscription_subscription_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, allocationSize enter code here= 1, name = "subscription_subscription_id_seq", sequenceName = "subscription_subscription_id_seq")
@Column
private Long subscriptionId;

@Column
private String template;

@Column
private String fileFormat;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "mail_id", referencedColumnName = "mail_id")
private MailDetail mailDetail;

}
```

MailDetail.class -

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
public class MailDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mail_detail_mail_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1, name = "mail_detail_mail_id_seq", sequenceName = "mail_detail_mail_id_seq")
    @Column
    private Long mailId;

    @Column
    private String emailId;
}
```

So this creates two audit tables, **subscription_aud** and **mail_detail_aud**.
Creation/Updates in mail_detail table is done through Subscription repository only. So my requirement is that whenever there is a change in mail_details table's fields, I need an audit entry in subscription_aud. Or basically i want change in mail_detail table be considered as a change in subscription table.

I am using hibernate envers for auditing. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @See [MappedSuperClass](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) for more  details.

Comment: I read it. How would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not with how Envers is currently designed.

Any *to-many* association that is either had its contents modified or elements in the collection changed will propagate an audit change for the owning side of the relationship by default; however that can even be disabled by setting `org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change` to *false*.  When this configuration setting is disabled, only element-collections will propagate a change to the owner because elements in such a collection are not entities, therefore can only be queried through the owning entity.

For *to-one* associations, this is a completely different story.

The only way to accomplish what you want would be to introduce some column on your `Subscription` instance that owns the `MailDetail` and change the value of that column when this use case happens.  Based on the fact you only modify `MailDetail` via the aggregate root `Subscription`, this should work however I agree that its less than ideal.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification and the suggestion naros! I found out that for my use case, i can do without achieving this mapping. But it’s good to learn about this fact. Thanks!